# Nonvanishing of Hom and tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M\neq 0$ an $R$-module. Show that if for every $R$-module $X\neq 0$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,X)\neq 0$ then $M\otimes_R X\neq0$ for every $R$-module $X\neq 0$.

Comment: I removed the "non-commutative algebra" tag as this is about commutative rings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X\ne0$, then $\operatorname{Hom}(X,X)\ne0$, hence by assumption  $\operatorname{Hom}(M,\operatorname{Hom}(X,X))\ne 0$. But the latter is also $\operatorname{Hom}(M\otimes X,X)$.

Comment: Perhaps you should say that you used the tensor - hom adjunction in your proof above. +1 anyway for your answer.